# Use of @Import Annotation

Tags: spring-security

I have started working on Spring Security. I am doing a HelloWorld application from [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-annotation-example/) link.

My **question** is, why do we need the `@Import` annotation?

While working on Spring MVC, I used to define a similar configuration file, but since it was in the same package, I did not need to import it. Why am I importing the `SecurityConfig.java` file here, then?

The place where I have used the `@Import` annotation is **here**

`AppConfig.java`:

```java
package com.mkyong.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.mkyong.web.*" })
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver
                          = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the security into the main app config class because it won't be picked up by the `@ComponentScan` because the class is not within the package for scanning `@ComponentScan({ "com.mkyong.web.*" })`. The security config is not defined in there. You register your main class like:

```java
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
    }
```

If you don't import the security class into it then the security won't be registered in the application.